# not able to execute crystal report in visual studio 2010

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, 64-bit

I am working on visual studio 2010..windows form application
i am try to create one crystal report.but while executing am getting error like this:
[image]

Then I added `crdb_adoplus.dll` to my refernce.but then also am getting same erro
my Target Frame work is `.Net FrameWork 4`

while coming to this line:

```
rpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))
```

then I edited `crdb_adoplus.dll` this property to **unblock** and clicked apply..after that am getting error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'crdb_adoplus.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.":"crdb_adoplus.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

my self i resolved this issue ,,i changed my app.config file like this:

```
 <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
```